# What does negative value of -1 in kB_rd/ and kB_wr/s mean in PIDSTAT command

Tags: linux, performance, testing

This is a sample output from running pidstat.

```
minflt/s majflt/s   VSZ          RSS    %MEM    kB_rd/s kB_wr/s kB_ccwr/s

49     0          217532      18784   0.01    -1      -1      -1
```

Can you please tell me how to manipulate the values in terms of high values, low values, zero values and -ve values. Alteast some direction of where to find will be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have it confirmed that the values cannot be -1. But if you get a -1 value it simple means the corresponding setting is missing from the setting file in config under boot dir.

Answer (score 1):

Only root can access disk statistics for processes that they do not own. Try to execute pidstat with sudo.